# ./configure parameters to build C library for iOS

Tags: ios, c, xcode

I'm writing an iOS application that runs an xml-rpc server. I'm using the C library for xml-rpc available here : http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/ . The library uses `./configure` to generate the makefile according to the host architecture, and `make, make install` to build/install the library.

I need to use this library with my iOS application. I understand that XCode uses a completely different build system, and I'm new to iOS development, so I'm not quite sure how to tie in the library with my application. What options do I need to pass in with ./configure to compile the library for iOS architectures (I understand there are three targets, armv7, armv7s and i386)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the configure script options for the simulator and device platforms.

1. Simulator (i386) :

   `$ ./configure --host=i386-apple-darwin --prefix <path_to_binaries> CFLAGS="-arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/ -miphoneos-version-min=4.0 --disable-cplusplus`
   `$ make`
   `$ make install`
2. iOS device (arm) : this is a bit trickier, and there's an unresolved [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25019656/linker-error-trying-to-link-against-arm-but-linker-using-x86) with this, but here are the general steps:

   `$ ./configure --host=arm-apple-darwin --prefix <path_to_binaries> CFLAGS="-arch armv7s -isysroot /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=4.0" --disable-curl-client --disable-cplusplus LDFLAGS='-arch armv7s -miphoneos-version-min=4.0 -isysroot /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk’`
   `$ make`

Notes specific to this library : We need to build gennmtab against x86, since it defines the symbol table and is to be run on the machine compiling the program - run the following commands (starting from the base xmlrpc-xx.xxx directory)

```
$ cd lib/expat/gennmtab/
$ rm gennmtab gennmtab.o 
$ gcc -c gennmtab.c -o gennmtab.o -DNDEBUG -Wall -W -Wno-uninitialized -Wundef -Wimplicit -Winline -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wmissing-declarations -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -fno-common -g -O3 -D_THREAD -I/Users/sradhakrishnan/dev/xmlrpc-c-1.25.28 -Isrcdir/lib/util/include   -I/Users/sradhakrishnan/dev/xmlrpc-c-1.25.28 -Isrcdir/lib/util/include
```

Now that gennmtab has been built against x86, continue with previous make, by running the following:

```
$ cd ../../../ (you are back in the base xmlrpc-xx.xxx directory)
$ make
$ make install
```

Comment: What should I replace "path_to_binaries" with? Is that the output folder?