# Linker error - trying to link against arm, but linker using x86

Tags: ios, c, linker, cross-compiling, ld

I'm attempting to cross compile [this C library](http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/techsupp.php) as an iOS library, i.e., for an armv7 machine. I'm using an OSX machine to compile the library. The project is setup to use [Autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) - here are the options i'm using :

`./configure --host=arm-apple-darwin --prefix ~/dev/xmlrpc-c-1.25.28/iOS_bin_arm CFLAGS="-arch armv7s -isysroot /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=4.0" --disable-curl-client --disable-cplusplus LDFLAGS='-arch armv7s -miphoneos-version-min=4.0 --sysroot /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk'`

This compiles fine. The problem occurs in the linking stage:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file parse_datetime.osh, file was built for armv7s which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): parse_datetime.osh
ld: warning: ignoring file parse_value.osh, file was built for armv7s which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): parse_value.osh
ld: warning: ignoring file resource.osh, file was built for armv7s which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): resource.osh
ld: warning: ignoring file trace.osh, file was built for armv7s which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): trace.osh
ld: warning: ignoring file version.osh, file was built for armv7s which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): version.osh
ld: warning: ignoring file xmlrpc_data.osh, file was built for armv7s which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): xmlrpc_data.osh
ld: warning: ignoring file xmlrpc_datetime.osh, file was built for armv7s which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): xmlrpc_datetime.osh
ld: warning: ignoring file xmlrpc_string.osh, file was built for armv7s which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): xmlrpc_string.osh
```

and so on. The dylib files generated are built for x86 instead of armv7, which is the architecture my iOS application will link against - Xcode throws these errors when trying to build the project :

```
    ld: warning: ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file ~/dev/xmlrpc-c-1.25.28/iOS_bin_arm/lib/libxmlrpc_server_pstream++.7.25.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): ~/dev/xmlrpc-c-1.25.28/iOS_bin_arm/lib/libxmlrpc_server_pstream++.7.25.dylib
ignoring file ~/dev/xmlrpc-c-1.25.28/iOS_bin_arm/lib/libxmlrpc_server_cgi++.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7):~/dev/xmlrpc-c-1.25.28/iOS_bin_arm/lib/libxmlrpc_server_cgi++.dylib
```

and so on for every executable generated earlier using `./configure` and `make`.

Obviously, when I test my code on the simulator, all is well, since there are no cross-compilation issues.

I even tried specifying the LDFLAGS in the make command directly, but it's still trying to link against x86. Is there a way to tell the compiler to link against the specified architecture? I've checked the man page for `ld`, but I couldn't find anything that might help. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not an issue with the the closing quote. I must have missed it while pasting. I've made the change in the question. It shouldn't matter if I set them before the configure script, but like I mentioned, I even tried using the LDFLAGS directly with make. The compiler doesn't seem to take notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autoconf is basically my worst nightmare, so this solution may not be "correct" but can hopefully unblock you - it looks like the build config does not take into account LDFLAGS when linking on OS X.  It uses LDFLAGS_SHLIB, but I wasn't able to get it to override that from a command line argument.  Try this patch (note that I downloaded v1.25.29) -- all I did was add your arguments to the end of the existing link command for shared libraries.

```
neals-mbp: ~/xmlrpc-c-1.25.29> diff config.mk.in config.mk.in2
297c297
<   LDFLAGS_SHLIB = -dynamiclib -undefined suppress -single_module \
---
>   LDFLAGS_SHLIB = -dynamiclib -undefined suppress -single_module -arch armv7s -miphoneos-version-      min=4.0 --sysroot               /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk \
```

Comment: Ha! That seems to fix it. Oddly enough, it _was_ picking up the LDFLAGS, because I'd added `LDFLAGS=@LDFLAGS@` to the `config.mk.in` file, but apparently it had no effect..thanks a million!